# Pectic Enzyme (powder) for Beer !

Tags: beer, brewing

Can I use Pectic Enzyme (powder) for Beer ! ( What I understands it's for wine only )

Comment: What are you trying to acheive? Is it for a specific recipe that contains fruits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not needed for beer. Pectic enzyme (more correct pectin lyase) is used to degrade pectin in fruit and grape wine to improve clearing and removal of haze, because of pectins. Since malt, wort and beer do not contain pectin it is not needed.

Sources:

- [Pectin lyase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pectin_lyase)
- [Pectic enzymes and wine](http://winemakersacademy.com/pectic-enzymes-wine/)

Comment: I would add, if you use a lot of fruit in beer, (more then 50% sugars/SG from fruit) or fruit that has a lot of pectin. then it may be helpful to get it clear...

Comment: I agree that (in general) pectin is not needed for beer. However I believe barley does contain pectins - it certainly contains amylopectins. .But not in troubling amounts